# Recursion Function

Tags: java, recursion

I'm quite confused about my code as I am trying to make a program to convert a decimal number to a number system from 2 to 16, converting a decimal value to another number system using the recursive function my problem is writing down the number Decimal value:256 with a Target base of 8 so an octal number system but the output is 040 this is my current code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int DValue = 0;
    int TBase = 0;

    while (DValue != -1){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("decimal value: ");
        DValue = input.nextInt();



        if (DValue == -1){
            System.out.println("thank you for using the program. bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (TBase < 2 || TBase > 16){
            System.out.print("target base: ");
            TBase = input.nextInt();
        }

            System.out.print("value of " + DValue + " in base " + TBase + " is ");
            recursionFunction(DValue, TBase);

            TBase = 0;

    }

}
```

*Edited*

```
public static void recursionFunction(int Decimal, int Base){
    int result;

    if (Decimal== 0) {
        System.out.println(" " );
        return;
    }

    result = Decimal / Base;



    System.out.print(Decimal % Base);


    recursionFunction(result, Base);

}
```

Comment: First: change the names inside your method. You have somewhat sensible names in your `main` and then you switch over to the confusing and pointless `FirstInput`/`SecondInput` inside your `recursionFunction`. Second: you *first* divide by the base and *then* try to get the modulo from the result, which means you'll definitely lose the first digit. Get the modulo *first* and *then* divide.

Comment: Your method should return something.  Perhaps a string that represents the value after base conversion.

Comment: The phrase "decimal number" includes values with a fractional part, like 3.14. Your input is actually a "base 10 integer".  When converting to bases greater than 10, you'll also need to translate your remainder values greater than or equal to 10 to their letter equivalent: A=10, B=11, C=12, D=13, E=14, F=15.

Answer (score 0):

To convert between different numeric systems you have to divide `FirstInput` by `SecondInput` only after you have printed `FirstInput % SecondInput` to the output stream. You can see [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/number_system_conversion.htm) that describes the process. I think the best way to fix your code will be to remove the line `FirstInput = result` and just replace the argument in the recursive call with `result`. (I am talking about the non-edited code)

Moreover, for what you're doing no recursion is required and the same effect can be achieved with a simple loop. When you call the function recursively in its end, you are effectively doing a loop, but also filling up the stack.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance I've inputted what you've recommended which is 

'       result = Decimal / Base;

        Base = result;

        System.out.print(Decimal % Base);

        recursionFunction(result, Base); '

Though the output is 004 is there any way to move the 4 to be the first number?

Comment: Switch the ORDER of your System.out.print() and the recursive call?

Comment: Oh, it worked thank you!, I only have one problem now This is the result Decimal:256 Base:8 the answer is 400 but the problem is the value of 256 in base 8 is  (The 400 is not beside the is but in a new line?
400

Comment: Change `System.out.println(" " );` to `System.out.print(" " );`. **note println() changed to print()**